# Show messages according to the MySQL database data? C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, windows-store-apps, int

I want to get the values from MySQL database and that would need to show the messages according to values. But it does not happen and that will always show `int privilege` is 0. If I did not assign that default value, errors  will be showing on the code.

How can I solve this issue and show messages according to the `int privilege` values?

```
private void button_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string username = usernameInput.Text;
    string password = passwordInput.Password;
    int privilege = 0;

    try
    {                
        //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
        string Query = "SELECT`tbl_user_login`.`u_id`,`tbl_user_login`.`u_username`,
                 `tbl_user_login`.`u_password`,`tbl_user_login`.`u_privilege` 
                 FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_user_login`WHERE `tbl_user_login`.`u_username` = '"
                 + username + "' AND `tbl_user_login`.`u_password` ='" + password 
                 + "' AND `tbl_user_login`.`u_privilege` = @privi;";
        MySqlConnection conn = 
                     new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@privi", privilege);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader;
        conn.Open();
        MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          // Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.

        if (MyReader.HasRows && this.Frame != null)
        {
            while (MyReader.Read())
            {

                if (privilege == 1)
                {
                    DisplayMsgBox("click ok to open the admin page ", "OK");
                }
                if (privilege == 2)
                {
                    DisplayMsgBox("click ok to open the staff page ", "OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayMsgBox("privilege 0", "ok");
                }   
            }
        }                
        else
        {
            DisplayMsgBox("sucess else", "ok");
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        DisplayMsgBox("sucess catch", "ok");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you're trying to do is checking the value of `u_privilege` column from `tbl_user_login` table instead of making a where condition based on `privilege`. You need to remove this where condition

```
AND `tbl_user_login`.`u_privilege` = @privi
```

and also remove the parameter assignment

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@privi", privilege);
```

You can get the value of `tbl_user_login.u_privilege` by using [MySqlDataReader.GetInt32](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader-getint32) syntax inside `while (MyReader.Read())` block

```
MyReader.GetInt32(3)
```

Please note that `3` is used because `MyReader.GetInt32` requires a zero based index parameter and `tbl_user_login.u_privilege` is the fourth column from your query. The value should be assigned to `privilege` variable as below

```
privilege = MyReader.GetInt32(3)
```

On a side note, you should parameterize your query to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here's the complete code after implementing the above changes

```
int privilege = 0;

try
{                
    //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
    string Query = "SELECT`tbl_user_login`.`u_id`,`tbl_user_login`.`u_username`,
             `tbl_user_login`.`u_password`,`tbl_user_login`.`u_privilege` 
             FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_user_login`WHERE `tbl_user_login`.`u_username` = 
             @username AND `tbl_user_login`.`u_password` = @password;";
    MySqlConnection conn = 
                 new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
    MySqlDataReader MyReader;
    conn.Open();
    MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      // Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.

    if (MyReader.HasRows && this.Frame != null)
    {
        while (MyReader.Read())
        {
            privilege = MyReader.GetInt32(3)

            if (privilege == 1)
            {
                DisplayMsgBox("click ok to open the admin page ", "OK");
            }
            if (privilege == 2)
            {
                DisplayMsgBox("click ok to open the staff page ", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMsgBox("privilege 0", "ok");
            }   
        }
    }                
    else
    {
        DisplayMsgBox("sucess else", "ok");
    }

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception )
{
    DisplayMsgBox("sucess catch", "ok");
}
```

Comment: yeah its work and i want to know y u used that privilege = MyReader.GetInt32(3) and what does mean (3)

Comment: `MyReader.GetInt32` means getting the value of the nth column of the query result to an integer, assuming the column is an integer, and 3 means the fourth column of the query result if using zero based index, i.e 0 means first column, 1 means second column, and so on.

Comment: i have no way to give you reputations:(

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong, the privilege is being returned as a string type. Try take it in as a string then cast it to an integer?